# Ubuntu 16.04 login loop on update

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-16.04

I read through all solutions proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and elsewhere. None of them worked. Here is how .xsession-errors look like:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gpg-agent pre-start process (2326) terminated with status 1
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2413) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2398) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (2306) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_indicator-application_indicator-upstart: application-service.1000.crash) main process (2354) killed by TERM signal 
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2399) killed by TERM signal 
upstart: unity7 main process (2411) killed by TERM signal 
upstart: hud main process (2423) killed by TERM signal 
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2421) killed by TERM signal 
upstart: window-stack-bridge main process (2332) killed by KILL signal
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://askubuntu.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution (somewhat, see below) worked for me.

1. Do a Ctrl + Alt + F3 to go into tty terminal from the graphical login screen.
2. Login with your usual credentials.
3. Run this command:

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*

4. After you reboot, login using the graphical login screen.
5. I saw a menu notifying me 'Ubuntu is running very low resolution graphics' and asked me what to do. I chose the default. YMMV.

I still see other posters elsewhere recommending installing nuevo for high quality graphics. I have not done this part yet.

Those who are looking for a programming aspect to this question see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/803390/620828) where the poster is asking for a kernel based solution to this.